# Sometimes images do not load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app I have an issue where sometimes not all images are loaded. It is usually one or two images, but I have seen it go to at least 5.

When an image is gone (for example in a `ListView`), all the images that point to the same file are gone. For example a `ListViewItem` has a cross in the right-hand corner, it is either there for the entire list or not at all for the entire list.

It takes a while to reproduce (10 to 30 minutes), but I always get the issue. My app does not go over 100MB in debug mode and all images are local (the app is not connected to the internet).

Sometimes the images are loaded by directly (hardcoding) the image in the XAML like so:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Images/BackButton.png"/>
```

Or sometimes by having a binding to a property in my class:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
public string Image { get; set; }
```

Both of these loading methods cause the image not to show up sometimes.

My users have also reported text not showing up correctly, but I have not been able to reproduce that one. I mention it because it might be related.

**EDIT:** I have noticed that when the computer is in a low-memory state (ex: other programs are using 90% of the computer's memory) the images get removed. Is there a way to disable removal of the images to free up memory?

Comment: Is there any logic behind showing the image to the imagebox? I mean, shall it display the same image during the whole run time? as like just a logo or an icon or something

Comment: If I load it with a hardcoded path to the image, I do not change it. If it is loaded with the binding, I do not change the property it refers to (I don't know if the listview in UWP recycles cells, but the listview scrolls, so it changes there if the listview recycles cells)

Comment: @FirstStep some of these images are icons, some are a bit bigger (400x400px max I think)

Comment: This is a tough one without being able to reproduce locally. Some tips though, if an image is flat like for example a generic Back Button icon, convert it to path data and display as a vector instead of an image file. If you have to use image files, at least run them through compression like with [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.com) to cut your file sizes in half. Again though, really hard to say what's going on without seeing it first hand.

Comment: Which version of the OS is that on? I remember seeing similar problems when I was working on Fresh Paint in Windows 8.1 times. The ugly fix I resorted to was to set `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` on the images. It was a platform bug causing this and setting the `CacheMode` would fix it, although it's typically not recommended.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I will try that out and get back to you. I currently have trouble filling my memory, as I don't have the crappy laptop with me.

Comment: I'm sure there are tools that would do that for you. The problem is - you might need to make sure it's the video memory that gets full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` on the images might work around a possible platform bug that would cause it.

If the issue is caused by memory pressure - you might want to make sure to use lower resolution images and use images that are at resolution appropriate to your screen resolution. At the very least - you might want to look into things like [`DecodePixelWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx) to ensure the resolution at which the images are loaded isn't too high.

Comment: `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` did the trick for me (at least, I haven't been able to reproduce). Does `DecodePixelWidth` have a performance hit? If so, how big in comparison with loading images that are too big?

Comment: It should be faster to decode a large image file to a smaller image than load a full image file, just because you otherwise have lots of memory to allocate.